# How to stop a JavaScript timer at 0:0

Tags: javascript, timer

I have this code for a timer, i am trying to get it to stop at 0:0 but it keeps going into negative numbers. any ideas to fix this would be a help.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      function startTimer(m,s)
      {
        document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML= m+":"+s;
        if (s==0)
        {
          if (m == 0)
          {
            clearTimeout(t);
          }
          else if (m != 0)
          {
            m = m-1;
            s = 60;
          }
        }
        s = s-1;
        t=setTimeout(function(){startTimer(m,s)},1000);
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <button onClick = "startTimer(0,5)">Start</button>

    <p id = "timer">00:00</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

You're always firing a new timer at the end of `startTimer`, even when you reach zero.  The quick fix is to add a `return;` <strike>after</strike> instead of `clearTimeout(t);`.

Comment: The `clearTimeout` isn't really necessary though, as by that point that iteration of the timeout has already completed.

Comment: Thank you that helped a lot! now i need to work out how to pause it.

Answer (score 0):

you can make the timeout function external and call it when time is more than 0:0 like this:

```
  function startTimer(m,s)
  {
    document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML= m+":"+s;
    if (s==0)
    {
      if (m == 0)
      {
        alert('done');
      }
      else if (m != 0)
      {
        m = m-1;
        s = 60;
        t();
      }
    }
    s = s-1;
    t();
    function t(){setTimeout(function(){startTimer(m,s)},1000)};
  }
```

or shorthand version:

```
  function startTimer(m,s)
  {
    document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML= m+":"+s;
      (s == 0) ? (m == 0 ? alert('done') : (m--, s = 60, t())) : (s--, t());
      function t(){ setTimeout(function(){startTimer(m,s)},1000)};
  }
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arcm111/8Lkaq/)

Answer (score 0):

Just a comment—the function can be a lot slimmer:

```
function pad(n) {
  return (n<10? '0':'') + n;
}

function startTimer(m,s) {
  document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = pad(m) + ":" + pad(s);
  s -= s? 1 : m-- && -59;
  if (m != -1) 
    setTimeout(function(){startTimer(m,s)},1000);
}
```

It will slowly drift as setTimeout doesn't run at exactly the time specified so it should use a date object to adjust the lag to the next full second.

Answer (score -1):

its an old code that ive written:

```
          function CountDown(TimeToCount){

        if(First)
        {
            var startDatum=new Date();
            First = false;
            date.a = startDatum;
            bye = TimeToCount-200;
        }
        if(bye > 0 && CDown){
            var zielDatum=new Date();
            bye =Math.abs(Math.floor(( ((zielDatum-(TimeToCount-200)-date.a)/1000) - 0.1)*10)/10);

            if ( bye * 10 % 10 ==0)

                $(".CountDown").html(bye+".0");
            else
                $(".CountDown").html(bye);
            setTimeout(function(){CountDown(TimeToCount)},20);

        }
            else
        {           $(".CountDown").html("0.0");

        }
               }`
```